Is there a formula to find the number of unpaired electrons for elements with atomic numbers up to 30?
I've been working on determining the number of unpaired electrons in atoms, specifically for elements with atomic numbers up to 30 (hydrogen through zinc).
While, I can manually calculate unpaired electrons based on electron configurations, it can be time-consuming, especially for transition metals where -orbital electrons come into play.
Is there a general formula or shortcut, to determine the number of unpaired electrons for these elements without writing out the full electron configuration each time? I’d appreciate any methods or tips that can make this quicker and more intuitive.

Do you understand why different atoms have different configurations? What is the point of using a formula?

The periodic table is pretty well-laid out! There's a reason why atoms have been organized in groups and periods.

If you have configuration, then there's nothing time consuming to tell how many unpaired electrons are there.

The problem is here I mentioned only atoms, when ions and transitional metals especially beyond Ru like complexities are come, the formal method is quite uneasy.
